# Getting more than 50 000 results crash the server on Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I'm trying to get 400 000 results from a database with Laravel. My problem is that the server gives me a **500 error code**, but does not generate a log file.
When I put a limit on my query, it works, but the limit is arround 20 000.
Maybe it's the php ini file, but I configurated it like this:

```
max_execition_time : -1
max_input_time : -1
max_input_vars: -1
memory_limit: -1
post_max_Size: -1
```

While Laravel gives a 500 error code with the limit, the server doesn't give an error. I need the 400 000 results.

*(from OP in the comments):*
The code is simply get all table order by datetime

Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't load 400.000 records at once, what could possibly be the reason to do this? Could you post the code and why you need this?

Comment: Its an historical table, if you want to see all the registers you will use this table, the code is simply, get all table order by datetime @Jerodev

Comment: Fetching 400'000 is never a good idea and shouldn't be done. I think you're creating some statistics or something with the data or merge it together? I would do this step by step by using limit or something other depending on the attributes in the db.

Comment: Don't do it. Use paginate, man.

Comment: @thmspl Hi, but i have to create an historial table, its not my decision.

Comment: you can create in batch. Don't need to do it at once.

Comment: @TsaiKoga The problem is not on fronted, is on backend, the server crash trying to get the data

Comment: Firstly you should load such amount of data together , if you insist to do so kindly set max_allowed_packet in mysql configuration file.

Comment: Check your server logs instead

Comment: @DavidVictoriaMartinez I advise you to read my answer completly. Don't do something with 400'00 at once. Do it step by step and you will not have any problems.

Comment: Server is crashing due to MySQL database , you must set configuration listed in my previous comment.

Comment: @DavidVictoriaMartinez I means if you have 100000 records, you can get 1000 from db, and them create your history table, and then get another 1000 record and then insert them...

Comment: Even if you should load all historical data, nobody is going to read 400.000 records at once. You should use pagination for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out:

[Eloquent collection chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-chunk)

[query builder chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#chunking-results)

Use `chunk` to get records in batch, and insert them in batch:

```php
Model::orderBy('id')
      ->select(['col1', 'col2', ...])
      ->chunk(100, function ($records) {
          // Create your array here:
          $inserted_array = [];
          foreach($records as $record) {
             $inserted_attr = [];
             $inserted_attr['column1'] = $record->col1;
             $inserted_attr['column2'] = $record->col2;
             ...
             $inserted_array []= $inserted_attr;
          }
          // And inserted 100 records at once.
          History::insert($inserted_array);
       });
```